# Template operator << overloading and make_pair

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have some problems overloading operators with template members and using make_pair:

```
class MyArchive
{
    public:
    template <class C> MyArchive & operator<< (C & c)
    {

        return (*this);
    }
};

class A
{

};

int main()
{

    MyArchive oa;
    A a;
    oa << a; //it works
    oa << std::make_pair(std::string("lalala"),a); //it doesn't work
    return 0;
}
```

I get this *interesting* error:

```
/home/carles/tmp/provaserialization/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/carles/tmp/provaserialization/main.cpp:30: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘oa << std::make_pair(_T1, _T2) [with _T1 = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _T2 = A]((a, A()))’
/home/carles/tmp/provaserialization/main.cpp:11: note: candidates are: MyArchive& MyArchive::operator<<(C&) [with C = std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, A>]
```

Any ideas about why it doesn't find `operator<<` in the second case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter of `operator<<` should be `const` :

```
template <class C> MyArchive & operator<< (const C & c)
```

Because `std::make_pair` returns a temporary object which cannot be bound to non-const parameter. But a temporary object can be bound to a `const` parameter, since then the life of the temporary extends, till the end of the called function.

---

A simple demonstration:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T & c) { cout << " non-const parameter" << endl; }

template<typename T>
void f(const T & a) { cout << "const parameter" << endl; }

int main() 
{
     f(make_pair(10,20.0)); //this calls second function!
}
```

Output:

> const parameter

See the output yourself here: http://www.ideone.com/16DpT

EDIT:

Of course, the above output explains only that temporary is bound to the function with const-parameter. It doesn't demonstrate life-extension. The following code demonstrates life-extension:

```
struct A 
{
  A() { cout << "A is constructed" << endl; }
  ~A() { cout << "A is destructed" << endl; }
};

template<typename T>
void f(T & c) { cout << " non-const parameter" << endl; }

template<typename T>
void f(const T & a) { cout << "const parameter" << endl; }

int main() 
{
     f(A()); //passing temporary object!
}
```

Output:

> A is constructed
>   const parameter
>   A is destructed

The fact that `A is destructed` after the function prints `const parameter` demonstrates that A's life is extended till the end of the called function!

Code at ideone : http://www.ideone.com/2ixA6

Comment: Not sure if the rationale is very convincing, though, because the temporary sticks around until the end of the expression (at least until the function returns) anyway, and doesn't need any extending.

Comment: Thanks! I now understand the problem. Another way to solve the problem was passing the argumnet by copy.

Answer (score 2):

Use "C const & c" not "C & c"

Your temporary pair returned from make_pair cannot bind to the reference expected by your operator<<, only to a const reference.

Answer (score -1):

This does work though:

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>

class MyArchive
{
  public:
  template <class C> MyArchive & operator<< (C & c)
  {
    return (*this);
  }
};

class A
{

};

int main()
{
  MyArchive oa;
  A a;
  oa << a; //it works
  oa << (std::make_pair(std::string("lalala"),a)); //it works
  return 0;
}
```

I guess it has something to do with name resolution.

Comment: On Visual Studio ? But Visual Studio allow many things that other compilers disallow. I think @ChAoS is trying on linux.